# Creating table in Oracle 11g with multiple foreign keys with - ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Tags: oracle

I followed the previous instruction of placing commas after each of the CONSTRAINTS.  However, on this table, it's giving me the following error message:

> ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint

All the foreign key tables that are associated with this table are created successfully. What is missing here?

```
CREATE TABLE FIELD (
ENCT_ID VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
FLD_NUM NUMBER NOT NULL,
FLD_DESC VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
SYMPT_CODE VARCHAR2(25),
DIAG_CODE VARCHAR2(25),
TEST_ID VARCHAR2(25),
RM_ID VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
AX_CODE VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
PROV_ID VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
MED_NDC VARCHAR2(25),
PRIMARY KEY (ENCT_ID, FLD_NUM),
CONSTRAINT FK_ENCOUNTER FOREIGN KEY (ENCT_ID) REFERENCES ENCOUNTER(ENCT_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_SYMPTOM FOREIGN KEY (SYMPT_CODE) REFERENCES SYMPTOM(SYMPT_CODE),
CONSTRAINT FK_DIAGNOSIS FOREIGN KEY (DIAG_CODE) REFERENCES DIAGNOSIS(DIAG_CODE),
CONSTRAINT FK_TEST FOREIGN KEY (TEST_ID) REFERENCES TEST(TEST_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_ROOM FOREIGN KEY (RM_ID) REFERENCES ROOM(RM_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_ASSESSMENT FOREIGN KEY (AX_CODE) REFERENCES ASSESSMENT(AX_CODE),
CONSTRAINT FK_PROVIDER FOREIGN KEY (PROV_ID) REFERENCES PROVIDER(PROV_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_MEDICATION FOREIGN KEY (MED_NDC) REFERENCES MEDICATION(MED_NDC));
```

Comment: Please don't tag every DBMS. Only tag the relevant one.

Comment: I apologize for my error. I missed the "(" on the CREATE TABLE LINE. Even after placing, I still get ORA-02260: table can have only one primary key. How can I get two Primary Keys.

Comment: I am not an Oracle guy but you can't have two primary keys in any DBMS. That goes against the entire concept of a primary key. You can have a composite key which is a primary key over more than 1 column but there can be one and only one primary key per table. There is NO variance on that.

Comment: In Oracle (and most DBs) there is only one Primary Key (PK) per table. You can have more natural unique keys on other columns.  If you are wanting to have the PK be ENCT_ID AND FLD_NUM then remove the PRIMARY KEY from the FIELD list and add this in the constraint section CONSTRAINT PK_NAME PRIMARY KEY (ENCT_ID,FLD_NUM)

Comment: So you understand that you created a composite key which is a primary key that spans two columns.

Comment: @TheMadDBA I would say ALL DBMS. The idea of more than one primary key violates the concept of what a primary key is in relational theory. If you know of a DBMS that allows this I would be interested to see it.

Comment: I apologize for tagging many places. It is my first time using this site, and it recommended me to tag more than one place to get better result. It was not done intentionally.

Comment: I understood about not have two primary keys. How can I create composite key?

Comment: After creating "PRIMARY KEY ((ENCT_ID, FLD_NUM)," it give me the following error message: ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint

Comment: @Sean Lange: I would hope all DBs handle PKs appropriately. Certainly all of the major players in the market today do (DB2,Oracle,MS SQL,etc). I  said most DBs because there is always some flaky DB out there that may not follow that. I know that OpenEdge has a primary index concept but it isn't a PK as we know it.

Comment: @TheMadDBA interesting. I have not heard of OpenEdge. I may have to go investigate now.

Comment: It used to be called Progress. It still only allows one primary index per table but there are no true PK/FK concepts in the database itself. OpenEdge is more of a niche database. Technology wise it is still back in the late 80s for the most part with some modern things thrown in.

Comment: Then why is this in the Database text book? I don't understand.

Comment: @SGIL I think you are confused between a composite key and two primary keys. They are not the same thing. A primary key is the column or columns required to uniquely identify a given row within a table. You can have a second column with a unique constraint but that is not the same thing as a primary key.

Comment: I got it @Sean Lange. I resolved it by removing all the CONSTRAINTs from the FOREIGN KEYs. Thank you.

Comment: Yes @SeanLange, I was a little confuse with two primary keys & composite keys, but I got it now. Thank you for all your help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've now basically completely changed the question.  The new error you're getting indicates that you've used one or more of these constraint names in the past.  Presumably on a different table.  `fk_room` probably isn't a great name for a constraint since many tables presumably want to have a foreign key that references the `room` table.  `fk_field_room` would be more likely to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE FIELD (
ENCT_ID VARCHAR2(25) PRIMARY KEY,
FLD_NUM NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
FLD_DESC VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,...
```

Remove any one primary key. It will be the index for the table. Like a School text books have only one index, same way, every table will have only one primary key.